# ! LaTeX Error: File `revtex4-1.cls' not found

Tags: revtex, miktex2.9

I am using MikTex2.9.6753-x64 in Windows 7.
I want to use the revtex4-1 class but I received the following error:

**! LaTeX Error: File `revtex*4-1*.cls' not found.**

I substituted revtex4-1 with revtex4-2 and then I received the following similar error:

**! LaTeX Error: File `revtex*4-2*.cls' not found.**

When I use Winedt10 again I receive exactly these errors.

Do you have any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome, please offer some code. How did you load the class, for example. Moreover, try to run `kpsewhich revtex4-1.cls` from your commandline/PowerShell and tell us the output.

Comment: Thank you. I called the class as follows: `\documentclass[sor, jor,  amsmath,amssymb, nofootinbib, a4paper, superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}`. I cannot find revtex4-1.cls to run it. Moreover I do not know how I can run a file from command line.

Comment: `revtex4-1` as mark as obsolete so MikTeX does not carry it anymore, use `revtex` it should be a dropin replacement. See https://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1?lang=en and https://ctan.org/pkg/revtex?lang=en

Comment: It sounds like you don't currently have `revtex` installed, and on-the-fly installation is either not enabled or not working. Open the MiKTeX console and find and install `revtex` from the list of packages, this contains the `revtex4-2` class that you should most likely be using.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. I opened MiKTeX packages and found that revtex and revtex4 were installed.

Comment: Can you add the first few lines of the log file when using `revtex4-2` to the question?